# _fseeki64() и fseeko64(), в чем отличия?

Tags: c, файлы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем разница между функциями **_fseeki64()** и **fseeko64()**?

В данный момент занимаюсь разработкой файловой утилиты. Столкнулся проблемой, которая заключается в том, что классические **fopen()**, **fseek()** и **ftell()** не умеют работать с файлами более 2 ГБ (по крайней мере, при использовании **MinGW x32**), а мне именно с такими файлами работать и нужно.

Попробовал решить проблему использованием **WinAPI**-шных функций: **CreateFile()**, **GetFileSize()** и пр. Системные вызовы неудобны по ряду причин. Хотелось бы разобраться со стандартными средствами языка, которые позволяют работать с большими файлами.

Плюс, стандартные средства все равно в своих недрах вызывают системные функции.

В общем, запутался окончательно.

Знаю про существование **fgetpos()** и **fsetpos()**, но как они пересекаются с определением размера файла и позиционированием за позицию > 2 147 483 647, так толком и не понял.

Comment: Это почему не умеют? fseek вторым параметром принимает long, ftell возвращает long. В чем проблема?

Comment: У меня sizeof(long) == 4, следовательно допустимый индекс позиционирования, а так же допустимый размер = 2 147 483 647.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эти функции не являются стандартными, они доступны лишь в том или ином компиляторе под ту или иную платформу. А предназначены они для одного и того же - для работы с большими файлами.

Функция [`_fseeki64()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75yw9bf3.aspx) специфична для Visual Studio (т.е. реализована в ран-тайм библиотеках студии и доступна только под **Windows**) и портирована в Mingw как расширение. В Mingw объявление функции имеет следующий вид:

```
 __MINGW_EXTENSION int __cdecl _fseeki64(FILE *_File, __int64 _Offset, int _Origin);
```

Функция [`fseeko64()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Positioning.html) реализована в библиотеке GNU Lib C (glibc), которая доступна в **Unix** системах. В Mingw функция объявлена следующим образом:

```
int fseeko64(FILE* stream, _off64_t offset, int whence);
```

В доках к `fseeko64()` так же сказано, что для того, чтобы функция работала правильно, файл надо открывать при помощи функции `fopen64()`.

Соответственно, если вы хотите, чтобы ваш код работал под Linux (gcc) и под Windows (gcc от Mingw), то используйте `fseeko64`. Если же вы пишите только под Windows и хотите чтобы ваш код компилировался в Mingw и в MSVC - используйте `_fseeki64()`. Это если не привлекать дефайны и условную компиляцию.

Comment: Понял. Разобрался. Действительно, в моем случае нет вариантов, кроме использования Win API, т.к. fseeko64()/_fseeki64() не работают в моем окружении из-за веток условной компиляции. Решил не заниматься этими плясками с бубном. Реализовал на Win API - все работает. Что странно, 5 ГБ файл, записанный при использовании fopen() и fwrite() некорректно открывается при помощи "виндовой" CreateFile() - при достижении байта с порядковым номером (2^32)-1 система минут на 10-15 зависает, даже какой-то сервис запускается. Я так понял, файл просто нарушен за 4 ГБ пределом. Всем спасибо.